# How to perform one to many mapping on spark scala dataframe column using flatmaps

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am looking for specifically a flatmap solution to a problem of mocking the data column in a spark-scala dataframe by using data duplicacy technique like 1 to many mapping inside flatmap

My given data is something like this

```
|id |name|marks|
+---+----+-----+
|1  |ABCD|12   |
|2  |CDEF|12   |
|3  |FGHI|14   |
+---+----+-----+
```

and my expectation after doing 1 to 3 mapping of the id column will be something like this

```
|id |name|marks|
+---+----+-----+
|1  |ABCD|12   |
|2  |CDEF|12   |
|3  |FGHI|14   |
|2  |null|null |
|3  |null|null |
|1  |null|null |
|2  |null|null |
|1  |null|null |
|3  |null|null |
+---+----+-----+
```

Please feel free to let me know if there is any clarification required on the requirement part

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: what happends to the values in columns name and marks? are they explicitly set to null ?

Also, what's the expectation? is there any code that you have already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are attempting to generate data with a requirement of re-using values in the ID column.

You can just select the ID column and generate random values and do a union back to your original dataset.

For example:

```
 val data = Seq((1,"asd",15), (2,"asd",20), (3,"test",99)).toDF("id","testName","marks")

+---+--------+-----+
| id|testName|marks|
+---+--------+-----+
|  1|     asd|   15|
|  2|     asd|   20|
|  3|    test|   99|
+---+--------+-----+

import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val newRecords = data.select("id").withColumn("testName", concat(lit("name_"), lit(rand()*10).cast(IntegerType).cast(StringType))).withColumn("marks", lit(rand()*100).cast(IntegerType))

+---+--------+-----+
| id|testName|marks|
+---+--------+-----+
|  1|  name_2|   35|
|  2|  name_9|   20|
|  3|  name_3|    7|
+---+--------+-----+

val result = data.unionAll(newRecords)

+---+--------+-----+
| id|testName|marks|
+---+--------+-----+
|  1|     asd|   15|
|  2|     asd|   20|
|  3|    test|   99|
|  1|  name_2|   35|
|  2|  name_9|   20|
|  3|  name_3|    7|
+---+--------+-----+
```

you can run the randomisation portion of the code using a loop and do a union of all the generated dataframes.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer Dharman and cliff and its not wrong in any aspect, but my concern is to solve this problem by using flatmaps, so if u could help me with that please it would be really grateful

Comment: i don't understand the requirement of using flatmaps in your original post. flat map transformation is usually for when you have an array struct in one of your columns and you want to create multiple rows which are based on the elements in that array.

do you have that in your dataframe?